# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError When Creating New Android Project

Tags: android

I've tried installing (and re-installing) Android Studio several times now, and each time, Studio isn't able to create a new Android project.

When I attempt to do it from the initial Android Studio window (ie. with the basic **'Create', 'Open', 'Import'** etc options), I'm asked all of the questions in the wizard, but then I get a brief progress dialog, followed by nothing at all.

If I open the very incomplete project the process creates by choosing 'Open' from the list, I can then try choosing to create a new Android project from the menu.

This has exactly the same issue, however I DO get an error message in the output console this time...

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:  
com/sun/xml/internal/bind/v2/model/annotation/AnnotationReader (wrong name:
com/sun/xml/internal/bind/v0/model/qnnotation/AnnotationReader)
```

NOTE: When I installed Android Studio, it installed an incompatible JDK (1.8, not 1.7). I have had to go into my default project settings to change the JDK it uses back to 1.8.

Does anyone know how I can avoid this? Is there a place I should be downloading the **JXB** classes? Am I missing something in my JAVA paths?

Answer (score 1):

This appears to have been caused by a corrupt JRE installation.

Reinstalling JRE 8 seems to have fixed the issue and I can now create Android projects successfully in Android Studio.